# Typescript Mocha Testing, How to solve TypeError: is not a function?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js

Currently I have the following class:

```
import * as winston from 'winston';
const { combine, timestamp, printf, label, json} = winston.format;
import {isEmpty, isNil} from 'lodash';
import {Log} from './Log';

export class LoggingService {
  public static initializeKeys() {
    
    this.keys = {tag: 'tag'};
  }

  public static intialize() {
    this.initializeKeys();
    const maskFormat = winston.format((meta) => {
      meta[this.keys.tag] = 'WebProxyConsumer';
      return meta;
    })();

    const jsonLog = printf((info) => {
      return JSON.stringify(info);
    });

    this.logger = winston.createLogger({
      level: 'info',
      format: combine(
        timestamp(),
        jsonLog
      ),
      transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console(),
        new winston.transports.File( { filename: 'error.log', level: 'error', maxsize: 10000000})
      ],
      exceptionHandlers: [
        new winston.transports.Console(),
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'exceptions.log', maxsize: 10000000 })
      ]
    });
  }

  public static getDefaultLogger() {
    return this.logger;
  }

  public static error(error, label, data) {
    if (isNil(this.logger)) {
      LoggingService.intialize();
    }
    let logObj = new Log(null, null);
    logObj.level = 'error';

    if (!isNil(label)) {
      logObj.label = label;
    }
    if (!isNil(data)) {
      if (typeof data === 'string') {
        logObj.message = data;
      } else {
        Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
          const value = data[key];
          if (logObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            logObj[key] = value;
          } else {
            logObj.data[key] = value;
          }
        });
      }
    }
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      if (error.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
        logObj.message += ' Error Message: ' + error.message;
      }
      if (error.hasOwnProperty('stack')) {
        logObj.error_stack = error.stack;
      }
    }
    if (typeof error === 'string') {
      logObj.message += ' Error Message: ' + error;
    }

    if (isNil(logObj.device_id)) {
      delete logObj.device_id;
    }
    if (isNil(logObj.data) || isEmpty(logObj.data)) {
      delete logObj.data;
    }
    this.logger.log(logObj);
  }

  public static info(data, label) {
    if (isNil(this.logger)) {
      LoggingService.intialize();
    }
    let logObj = new Log(null, null);
    if (!isNil(label)) {
      logObj.label = label;
    }
    if (!isNil(data)) {
      if (typeof data === 'string') {
        logObj.message = data;
      } else {
        Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
          const value = data[key];
          if (logObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            logObj[key] = value;
          } else {
            logObj.data[key] = value;
          }
        });
      }
      if (isNil(logObj.device_id)) {
        delete logObj.device_id;
      }
      if (isNil(logObj.data) || isEmpty(logObj.data)) {
        delete logObj.data;
      }
      this.logger.log(logObj);
    }
  }

  private static logger: winston.Logger;

  private static keys: any;
}
```

I'm using mocha for unit testing and so far this is my unit test for the class:

```
    describe('LoggingService Tests', () => {
    const loggingService = new LoggingService();
    const loggingServiceProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(loggingService);
    it('Checking LoggingService Initialization', () => {
        expect(loggingServiceProto).to.not.be.null;
        expect(loggingServiceProto.combine).to.not.be.null;
        expect(loggingServiceProto.timestamp).to.not.be.null;
        expect(loggingServiceProto.printf).to.not.be.null;
        expect(loggingServiceProto.logger).to.not.be.null;
        expect(loggingServiceProto.keys).to.not.be.null;
    })
    it('Checking initializeKeys', () => {
        expect(loggingServiceProto.initializeKeys()).to.not.be.null;
    })
    it('Checking initialize', () => {
        expect(loggingServiceProto.intialize()).to.not.be.null;
        expect(loggingServiceProto.logger).to.not.be.null;
    })
    it('Checking getDefaultLogger', () => {
        expect(loggingServiceProto.getDefaultLogger()).to.not.be.null;
    })
})
```

The importing for mocha is correct and for my first test `'Checking LoggingService Initialization'`, I'm successfully passing. That's to say I'm able to initialize my class without a problem. The problem is with the rest of the tests I'm running. For those, I get the following errors:

```
TypeError: loggingServiceProto.initializeKeys is not a function
TypeError: loggingServiceProto.intialize is not a function
TypeError: loggingServiceProto.getDefaultLogger is not a function
```

Would anyone know why this is happening? These functions are defined and I'm not experiencing this issue with any other classes I'm testing using mocha.

Any advice would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: There are statics functions (You don't need to create an instance), so you could call like your class name, for example: LoggingService.initializeKeys() or you can remove the word static on your functions class.

Comment: `static` means that they are _not_ on the prototype. It means they are on the class object itself. Also, a class that _only_ has `static` members has no reason for existing. Just use an object or a export each member directly.

Answer (score 0):

something to do with tsconfig. remove tsconfig and see if test passes.
the test command should look like:

> mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts